# Home internet questions

Tags: router, internet, phone, coaxial

I just moved into a house which only century link can provide internet, which is through the phone lines. Although the house has female coax ports in almost every room, the only female phone line port is in the bedroom, which forces me to have the router in the bedroom. I also have my ps4 in the basement which I'd like hardwired to the router for the fastest internet I can get. At the moment, I have a long ethernet cord running from the upstairs bedroom all the way to the ps4 in the basement. Here's my question (before I buy all the equipment): would it work if I did the following?

phone jack in bedroom -> phone cord -> phone to coax adapter -> coax port in bedroom -> (maybe the coax port in the bedroom and the coax port in the basement are connected?) -> coax port in basement -> coax to phone adapter -> phone line -> router -> ethernet cord -> ps4

That way the router is out of the bedroom and I can hard wire the ps4 without a cord running through the house.

Potential downfalls:

the coax cables arent connected how I hope they are and I can't arbitrarily connect any two rooms together
If this is even possible, all the converting may slow down the ping?
I'm curious to what you guys think...

Comment: If you actually have *"coax ports"*, then these are unsuitable for phone or (modern) Ethernet unless special adapters are employed.   Typically *"internet ... through the phone lines"* requires an ADSL modem, but you only mention a *"router"*.  Maybe you need to provide photos and accurate details of what you actually have.

Comment: You need a router and ethernet cables to share a wired connection around your house.

Answer (score 1):

You state, "the only female phone line port is in the bedroom." By that, I assume you mean an RJ-11 or RJ-12 jack for POTS (Plain Old Telephone Service over copper paired wires). However, is that the **only** telephone in the whole house? If there are other phones, it takes just minutes to remove the old cover plate and replace it with a plate with RJ-45 jack. Further, for best signal, the jack should be as close to the phone service entrance as possible.

You can find where the phone lines enters the house, likely *in* the basement, and add a jack close to there.

Comment: I dont see how this answers the question.  Shouldn"t these statements be comments?

Comment: @davidgo, first, understand the question, and see what was omitted or  misunderstood in it.